# How to get real size (without shared layer) of multiples docker shipped together

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

## The problem

I am currently delivering a micro-services application with more than 20 Docker images. My goal is to optimize the Docker layer for minimum image size.

Since most of the images use the same layers (with minor changes), I'm interested in the final size of all my images together and have no interest in the size of a single image.

(I'm looking for uncompressed size if possible).

I'd like to know if there are any tools or commands to do this operation easily. I have some solutions, but they're not very clean...

## **Bad solutions**

**Solution 1 : docker system df**

1. clean all existing images
2. pull all my images
3. docker system df | grep image

Cons:

1. This need a fresh system for each test...

**Solution 2 : Docker save all my images**

Create one archive and docker save and compare the compressed size

Cons:

1. This is the compressed size
2. This is CPU intensive
3. This take too much time